# Common patterns for SPA to discover its own current version

Tags: javascript, client-server, single-page-application

Use case:

1. User browses to http://url.com/, which [eventually] results in a SPA at version 1.0.0 being downloaded to the client
2. SPA 1.0.0 depends on REST API running at version 1.0.0
3. User eventually abandons the app without closing the browser/tab -- possibly for hours or overnight
4. During the same time user has abandoned the app, a new version of the app and dependent APIs, 1.1.0, is deployed (maybe overnight)
5. User returns (maybe the next morning), and continues to use the SPA running at 1.0.0, which makes intermittent XHRs to APIs running version 1.1.0
6. Errors occur due to version mismatch between client/server

One thought I had was to have the SPA periodically checks (via XHR) to find out the current version of the application according to the server. However, if we take that approach, what is a reasonable interval? Maybe when we check for the validity of the bearer token? When the app becomes active after a period of inactivity?

Are there common patterns to deal with the scenario described above?

Comment: Are you versioning your APIs by URL? (example url.com/api/1.0.0/myendpoint).  If so, could you have that string built with an object kept in memory, and have the old endpoint prompt the UI code to update the version value and try the call again?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too-broad, because there are a bundle of ways to do this. You could mimic how Gitlab and most Node badge services handle it, with a central server that returns an image (or in your case, version number). You could write an endpoint in your services to do that, set it up in a balancer or proxy, all kinds of ways.